# Gradient not correct show on Android 4.0 and Android 4.1

Tags: android

Here my gradient (in folder `drawable`):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Here how I set this drawable:

```
                ConstraintLayout navDrawerItemMainContaner = view.findViewById(R.id.navDrawerItemMainContaner);
                Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.nav_drawer_row_selected_bg);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    navDrawerItemMainContaner.setBackground(drawable);
                } else {
                    navDrawerItemMainContaner.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                }
```

And here result on Androd 4.3+. And this is correct result.

[image: correct]

And here result on **Android 4.0** and **Android 4.1**

[image: incorrect]

Why on **Android 4.0** and **Android 4.1** gradient not correct show. Must be white.

Comment: what is `android:endColor` ?

Comment: no 'android:endColor'. This is a problem?

Comment: Yes , you are right. After I set "end:color" the problem is gone!

Comment: good, you can also use `centerColor` if you want